# Text to Speech Broken AVFoundation on iOS 17 Beta 1

Tags: ios, avfoundation

When playing audio from Text to Speech using AVSpeechSynthesisVoice with `Format | AVAudioFormat, Buffer | AVAudioPCMBuffer`, the audio is choppy and sounds distorted. This was not an issue on iOS 16 and below.

This issue happen in iOS 17 Beta 1

> Create an AVSpeechSynthesisVoice object.
> Set the format property of the AVSpeechSynthesisVoice object to AVAudioFormat.
> Set the buffer property of the AVSpeechSynthesisVoice object to AVAudioPCMBuffer.
> Speak text using the AVSpeechSynthesisVoice object.

Able to listen Text to Speech.

#ReportedToAppleFeedback

Comment: Have you reported this to Apple in a Feedback?

Comment: It's developer beta 1!

Comment: #Reported to Apple.
#IssueExist in Beta 2

Comment: #IssueExist in Beta 3